# I use expo and when the internet is weak it shows me this error

Tags: react-native, expo

This error is specific to expo-Notification and I want a solution to this problem, where try and catch does not cancel this error

[expo-Notification] error thrown while updating the device push token with the server TypeError Network request failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna share some code so that we get the issue. By what you have shared, I can only suggest you to use async await and wait until you get token or you can use @react-native-community/netinfo to get netinfo or atleast get info if the network is weak or not and based on those conditions you can carry out your operations.

Comment: Indeed, use @react-native-community/netinfo, and when the Internet connection is disconnected, this error does not appear, but this error appears only when the Internet is weak